# Can't compile inline assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, masm

I am unable to compile an assembly file in Visual Studio 2017.
I am unsure weather this is due to visual studio or because i made some mistakes in the code, pls help me.

I have a c++ main file in which I go for the call:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myStruct.h"

extern "C" __int64 CalcStructSum_(const myStruct *kekStruct);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   myStruct kek;
   kek.Val8 = 8;
   kek.Val16 = 16;
   kek.Val32 = 32;
   kek.Val64 = 64;


   __int64 summe = CalcStructSum_(&kek);

   printf("summe betraegt: %d", summe);
   getchar();

   return 0;
}
```

mystruct.h :

```
#pragma once

typedef struct
{
      __int8        Val8;
      __int8        Pad8;
      __int16       Val16;
      __int32       Val32;
      __int64       Val64;

 }myStruct;
```

here the assembly equivalent:

```
myStruct        struct
Val8    byte    ?
Pad8    byte    ?
Val16   word    ?
Val32   dword   ?
Val64   qword   ?
myStruct        ends
```

and here is the assembly file:

```
.model      flat,c
include     myStruct_.inc


.code

;prolog and function start

CalcStructSum_      proc

push    ebp
mov     ebp,esp
push    ebx
push    esi


; das struct liegt auf dem stack
; alle felder wurden auf 32 bit sign-extended
; in esi kommt anfang des speicherbereichs rein
; später wird quasi [basereg + dispatch] daraus interpretiert

mov     esi,    [ebp+8]     ; get a pointer to "mystruct"

; load 8- and 16bit sources into 32bit registers (movsx)
; this is necassery to load struct-fields from the stack

movsx   eax,    byte ptr [esi + myStruct.Val8]      ; [baser. + disp]
movsx   ecx,    word ptr [esi + myStruct.Val16]
add     eax,    ecx

; now sign-extend eax register to 64bit
; high part: edx , low part: eax
cdq

;save result for later
mov     ebx,    eax
mov     ecx,    edx

; now load the int-part of the struct and add it
; (it must be sign-extended to edx:eax again)

mov     eax,    [esi + myStruct.Val32]
cdq

; (the high-part must be added with carry, if overflown)
add     eax,    ebx
adc     edx,    ecx

; now, get the long from stack

add     eax,    dword ptr [esi + myStruct.Val64]        ; low part
adc     edx,    dwprd ptr [esi + myStruct.Val64 + 4]    ; high part

; we now have the sum of all structure fields in the register pair edx:eax

pop     esi
pop     ebx
pop     ebp

ret

CalcStructSum_ endp
end
```

Also, I included the files in my explorer window like this (and, of course, set build dependencies):
[image: project-explorer]

I also tried assembling from powershell with ml.exe, but no luck here either.
Also, it would be nice if someone could point out a simple method to capture the output of ml.exe, it is instantly away after execution (am a cmd-noob).

Finally, I tried putting the files in ANSI mode, but this should not be an issue at all, I just read through old stackoverflow answerers.

What am I missing? Should I turn back to VS2010 maybe? Or is it just an idiotic syntax error? This really freaks me out since such a simple proof-of-concept program should not be so hard to write -.-

Comment: What error diagnostics did you get.

Comment: I can't spot any inline assembly code in your example?

Comment: can u help me get error diagnostics at all? i am not very expierienced at debugging such codes. if you meant the console output: error MSB3721

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, isn't cpp called assembly function also called inline? pardon me if it is the wrong name and feel free to edit

Comment: @clockw0rk The term _inline assembly_ is used for assembly code which is inlined within c++ code.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but make sure that you compile your code for 32 bit instead of 64 bit as your assembly code is not going to work in 64 bit mode.

Comment: @fuz good point, but is set to x86 (tested it with a simple mov-oneliner)

Comment: @clockw0rk: x86-64 supports 32-bit addressing modes.  Did you test with `mov eax, [rdi]` or something to check that that *wouldn't* assemble, as a way of proving it was 32-bit?  `pop eax` requires 32-bit mode (or 16-bit mode), but `mov eax, [eax]` assembles just fine in any of the 3 modes.  (requires an address-size prefix in 16 and 64-bit modes, though, and an operand-size prefix in 16-bit mode.)

Comment: In Visual Studio before adding your assembler filesto the project did you set the build customizations so that it included building of MASM targets. Right mouse click the project and select build dependencies/customizations on the menu.Then in the selection box look the the MASM target and put a checkmark next to it. By default visualstudio projects don't enable MASM target building by default.

Comment: @PeterCordes The only proof I have is that this is my default workspace, i set everything to 32bit mode, and assembled some x86 codes before just fine. If I try accessing rax register, it does not assemble, this should be proof

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, I know that, and I compiled and linked some assembler programs with VS before. I get the feeling the VS2017 version is somehow bugged .... Can't proof that tho

Comment: You can't use RAX in 32-bit generated code

Comment: @clockw0rk: yes, if `mov rax, rdx` or something won't assemble, then you are building 32-bit code.  That's a sufficient double-check to make sure your settings are doing what you expect.

Comment: turned out a simple typeo in line 50 ruined everything. thanks for all your effords. if you want, write an answere and get some reputation for it, otherwise i will delete this shame of a question tomorrow

Comment: but, after all, i learned an important thing: ALWAYS use ml.exe /c to compile stuff, never let visual studio handle things for you or you will never get any good error messages

Comment: @clockw0rk Best would be if you could answer the question yourself so future readers with the same problem can receive the wisdom you gained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem is solved:

Turned out it was a by typo in line 50 [ "dwprd" instead of "dword" ].

Fixed and solved. 
If anybody comes accross a situation like mine, where they just can't find any usefull hints provided by the assembler / IDE , then here is how i found the solution:

[ in windows OS ]

1. Open explorer window and search for "ml.exe" (takes a long time)
2. Best practise is makeing a hardlink to this directory for ease of use
3. assemble only one file at a time with ml.exe, use flag "c" so the linker will stay calm and quiet [because c is for "don't link at all"]
4. "ml.exe -c" will provide some error output (for me something like "unknown command dwprd" or something like that), also there will be a .obj file created if successfull
5. after you fixed all occuring bugs and errors, go back to Visual Studio and compile, if you still have no luck, try moving the assembled .obj files to the VS projects folder.

Comment: Must be a problem in your environment.I'd create a new project from scratch, and then **first** ensure build customizations have MASM target listed (right mouse click project, select build dependencies and build customizations and put a check by the MASM targets). Then add your files into the project. I took the files as is in VS2017, created a project added the MASM target and when building the project the errors for MASM appeared Line 50 `dwprd` mistake.